# How can I create a footer for my website in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I want to create a footer for my website  using Flutter. I'm not figuring out how to do it. Maybe I should add different columns inside one row. Can someone show me how to do it. I would appreciate it. I 'm building a website for my next project Here's my code below:
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  //width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.grey[900],
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        //height: 150,
                        // width: 150,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const Text(
                        "Escorts",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Angenturen & Clubs",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Inserieren",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Werben",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Blog",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Kontakt",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.attach_money,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.chat,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '\nInserieren\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                          return Colors.pink;
                        }
                        return Colors.grey;
                      }),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Registrieren',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                          return Colors.pink;
                        }
                        return Colors.grey;
                      }),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                          return Colors.pink;
                        }
                        return Colors.grey;
                      }),
                    ),
                    // backgroundColor:
                    // MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[600])),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Kontakt',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: const [
                  Text('Escorts', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  Text('Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  Text('DSGVO', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  Text('Newsletter', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              child: Row(
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 267,
                    height: 80,
                  ),
                  Text('Agenturen & Clubs', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                  ),
                  Text('Registrieren', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 230,
                  ),
                  Text('Impressum', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 243,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  Text('Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet,\n consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive by this

```
           Scaffold(
             persistentFooterButtons:[ //Widgets],
             .....
```

Comment: I want to add at my footer Contact etc, you know. I dont know how can i do it here

Comment: just like:- persistentFooterButtons:[ Text("Contact), ... ]